# PHP utf8_en/decode deprecated, what can i use?

Tags: php, encoding, deprecated, decoding

90% of my website pages use the utf8 encoding feature for compile an DataTable.

```
$a[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $item);
```

With the old version 8.0 of php everything was fine, in the new version it gives me an error when a value of $item ($item is an array) is null.

What is a valid alternative?

Comment: Is `$item` actually ISO encoded to start with? Also, is `it gives me an error`, accurate or is it a deprecation notice? Please add message.

Comment: `utf8_encode` expects an string not NULL. So prepare the array and convert all NULL to empty string `array_map('strval', $item)` or filter null values `array_filter()`

Comment: utf8_encode does nothing to check the encoding type and just assumed it is ISO-8859-1. This leads to bugs and errors. There are better solutions such as the plugin mbstring. mb_convert_encoding lets you not just convert, but you can specify what you are converting from and to.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We know that `utf8_encode` is deprecated since PHP 8.2.0 and will be removed in PHP 9 https://php.watch/versions/8.2/utf8_encode-utf8_decode-deprecated

So the alternative can be:

```
$oldSample = ["\x5A\x6F\xEB"];
$result= array_map
(
    function ($item){
        return mb_convert_encoding($item, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($item));
    }, 
    $oldSample
);
var_dump($result);
```

Documentation:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php
  https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Can be shortened to:
```array_map(fn($item) => mb_convert_encoding($item, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($item)), $oldSample);```

Answer (score 10):

Use [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Example:

```php
$iso = "\x5A\x6F\xEB";
echo mb_convert_encoding($iso, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'); // Zoë
```