# PHP hex string error please help me fix it

Tags: php, hex

```
echo bin2hex('t«ikh«ngyªu'); //74c2ab696b68c2ab6e6779c2aa75 wrong result
//74AB696B68AB6E6779AA75 correct result
```

please help me fix it

error hex string

Comment: Could explain, why you think it is the correct / wrong result?

Comment: How do you know the correct result? The back and forth here works just fine https://onecompiler.com/php/3yt4yjh43

Comment: Any tool will give the right result: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-hex-convertor.php

Comment: Using the onecompiler mentioned above to transform the string given as correct to bin results in: `t�ikh�ngy�u`. So it's either in the way you create these strings or a text encoding issue. Which one do you intend to use?

Comment: Looking at `t«`. '74' is a ascii codepoint for 't'. And the `«` has an 'ab' codepoint in ascii latin-1. You are using UTF obviously, and the `«` has two-byte 'c2ab' codepoint there. Your entire string is 11 characters length. The hex string result may have length of 22 (your desired result) only when you'r using single-byte encoding. Which is not the case with UTF (unless you're below 7f codepoint).

Comment: thanks : echo bin2hex(utf8_decode('t«ikh«ngyªu')); //correct result

Comment: @LưuHậu utf8_decode is deprecated - have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74865684/php-utf8-en-decode-deprecated-what-can-i-use for an alternative.

Comment: @Jared mind to make your comment to an answer? And add the transformation from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 as well. `echo bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding('t«ikh«ngyªu', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'))`; gives the expected result.

Comment: @Uwe, sure. Done actually, thx for the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `t«`. '74' is a ascii codepoint for 't'. And the `«` has an 'ab' codepoint in ascii latin-1. You are using UTF obviously, and the `«` has two-byte 'c2ab' codepoint there. Your entire string is 11 characters length. The hex string result may have length of 22 (your desired result) only when you're using single-byte encoding. Which is not the case with UTF (unless you're below 7f codepoint).
If you need your input string in a non-UTF encoding, you should convert it first as @Uwe mentioned in the comments to the question:

```
echo bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding('t«ikh«ngyªu', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'));
```

But I'd recommend to stick to UTF.